# Is it possible in sqlalchemy core to access the underlying Select object from an Alias or CTE object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I can turn a CTE or Alias into a Select using `.select()`, but statements like `table.select().alias().select().cte().select().alias().select()` lead to unnecessarily lengthy compiled SQL.
Is there a better way to invert/undo the `.alias()` and/or `.cte()` operations?

I'm building queries that depend on shared subqueries using sqlalchemy core, and want to easily access a subquery as a CTE (for joining and using it as a subquery) and as a Select statements (for direct execution). I'm hoping to achieve this without having to keep track of both the original subquery and the output of `query.cte()` in parallel.

```
# preliminary setup
import pandas
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, create_engine, Table
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
pandas.DataFrame(data={'A': [1,2,3]}).to_sql('table1', engine, index=False)
table = Table('table1', MetaData(bind=engine), autoload=True)
# end of preliminary setup

table_select = table.select()
table_cte = table_select.cte()

print table_cte.select()  # works but lengthier than necessary
print table_select  # desired output
```

In brief, I'd like to have a function that takes table_cte as the input and outputs table_select.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is an attribute called `original` for exactly this purpose.

```
table_cte.original == table_select
table_select.alias().original == table_select
```

both return True.